# Graphlookup to build a link list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a link-list (hopefully returned as an array) from documents that
reference each other. I am using MongoDB aggregation framework so that I will return

4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 or [4,3,2,1]. What should I do to make this work?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$parent",
      "connectFromField": "parent",
      "connectToField": "postId",
      "as": "revisions",
      
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/uMoeQKJW9oN

```
[
  {
    postId: 1,
    parent: 0
  },
  {
    postId: 2,
    parent: 1,
    
  },
  {
    postId: 3,
    parent: 2,
    
  },
  {
    postId: 4,
    parent: 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Your playground works. Any specific form of output you are expecting?

Comment: The output I'm expecting is an ordered list of elements returned in an array of objects. [{postId:4, parent:3}, {postId: 3, parent: 2} ...so and so].